# Is it Bitcoin or Bitcoins in plural? How did Satoshi Nakamoto address this choice in his emails?

Tags: terminology

I understand that traditionally it is said 2 bitcoin, not 2 bitcoins. But recently I have seen Wikipedia state that "bitcoins" is the correct plural form.

We have words like water. It is never "waters". You never say "pass me the waters", or "I drank too much waters". It even sounds funny. We use water for both singular and plural.

I believe the best way to settle this debate regarding plural in bitcoin is to refer to the way Satoshi Nakamoto defined the plural expression of Bitcoin in his emails. Does anybody know how Satoshi Nakamoto used the plural form in his emails?

Comment: Really, nobody has the authority to decide what is correct, at best there may eventually be some social consensus on this question (though I wouldn't be surprised if different cultures/languages adopted different conventions here).

Answer (score 1):

Satoshi used *bitcoins* in bitcointalk posts.

> Right, the exchange rate between domains and **bitcoins** would float.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1790.msg28959#msg28959